# Save a picture in wrong folder using opencv

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

Directory I would need to save to:

```
DataBase-Faces\name
```

Directory where the code is saving:

```
DataBase-Faces
```

My code:

```
cv2.imwrite("DataBase-Faces\\"+name+str(frames)+".png",Faceimage)
```

My program creates a folder with the typed name, I have to record these images in that folder, and the name of each image will be called `Nome Typed + (frame number) .png`

Comment: You should not be concatenating paths by hand. Consider looking into the [`os.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html) module, which can save you from this sort of headache in the future.

Comment: how can i save images in a folder created by the program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're forgetting to put a directory separator between `name` and `str(frames`).

Try

```
image_path = '\\'.join(['DataBase-Faces', name, str(frames) + '.png'])
cv2.imwrite(image_path, Faceimage)
```

As a side note, you should not be concatenating paths by hand. Consider looking into the [`os.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html) module, which can save you from this sort of headache in the future.

Comment: thank you so much, I don't know why I received so many negative votes, I tried my best to show my doubts.

Comment: @VitorGonçalves Regarding the downvotes, its likely people perceived a lack of effort to solve this problem on your own. When posing future question, it's best to demonstrate your understanding of a problem and include the steps you have already taken to try to find a solution. In this case, `print`ing out the path produce by concatenating the strings would have been an easy first step, and would also have quickly revealed what was amiss.

Answer (score 0):

General the Code to save the image is something like that

```
cv2.imwrite('file.png',img)
```

For the 'file.png' u want to be

EXAMPLE

```
name = 'my_photo_album_name'
frames = 500
frame_name = f'{name}\{frames}'
cv2.imwrite(f'DataBase-Faces\{frame_name}.png', img)
```